# Cassandra : CQLSH not displaying correct timezone

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a table macrecord in cassandra as follows :

```
 macadd            | position | record | rssi1 | timestamp
-------------------+----------+--------+-------+---------------------
 D8:C7:C8:45:52:20 |       21 |     25 |     0 | 2015-09-25 08:41:00+0000
```

I am inserting timestamp values using dateof(now()) however the problem is CQLSH is just displaying the default UTC time and not adding the timezone offet `+0800` in my case. How can i display the correct timezone. I am on ubuntu 14.04 and my system time is correct.

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you running?  2.2.1 by chance?

Comment: Hi Aaron. Yes i am running 2.2.1. I have also tried version 2.1.9 and i can reproduce the issue on version 2.1.9 as well. Is this a bug?

Comment: I think so.  The Python formatting library was altered from the last release (to account for Windows time formatting), and the TZ offset is now coming out as zero in Bash.  I'm going to look at it while I fly home, create a JIRA for it, and (hopefully) a patch.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct TZ set in your environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361233/how-can-i-change-apache-cassandras-default-time-zone/28362147#28362147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the rub on this one.  [CASSANDRA-10000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10000) fixed some issues with date formatting in Windows.  But since each platform has its own way of keeping track of time zone offsets, it was difficult to make cqlsh work for Windows without including some additional dependencies for timezone display.  Therefore the path of least resistance was chosen, and now ALL platforms show queried timestamps in UTC.

I am going to create a JIRA ticket to address this, and get proper timezone display back for both environments (hopefully).

**USE THIS FIX AT YOUR OWN RISK**

If you feel comfortable trying it, here is how I fixed this for myself:

In `$CASSANDRA_HOME/pylib/cqlshlib/formatting.py`, look for the `strftime` method definition.  The new one (as of 2.2.1) contains only two lines:

```
def strftime(time_format, seconds):
    tzless_dt = datetime_from_timestamp(seconds)
    return tzless_dt.replace(tzinfo=UTC()).strftime(time_format)
```

You can clearly see where the UTC timezone is being forced.  Essentially, just comment-out (or remove) those lines, and replace them with the `strftime` method definition from Cassandra <= (2.2.0 || 2.1.8).  In case you don't have it, here is the code:

```
def strftime(time_format, seconds):
    local = time.localtime(seconds)
    formatted = time.strftime(time_format, local)
    if local.tm_isdst != 0:
        offset = -time.altzone
    else:
        offset = -time.timezone
    if formatted[-4:] != '0000' or time_format[-2:] != '%z' or offset == 0:
        return formatted
    # deal with %z on platforms where it isn't supported. see CASSANDRA-4746.
    if offset < 0:
        sign = '-'
    else:
        sign = '+'
    hours, minutes = divmod(abs(offset) / 60, 60)
    return formatted[:-5] + sign + '{0:0=2}{1:0=2}'.format(hours, minutes)
```

I have tested this code with the above situation, but certainly not to an exhaustive level.  Like I said, use at your own risk.  But this should hold you over until a patch gets written to restore this functionality.

**EDIT 20161021**

This was fixed in [CASSANDRA-10397](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10397) for versions 2.2.6, 3.0.4, and 3.4.

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/cqlsh", line 125, in <module>
    from cqlshlib.formatting import (format_by_type, format_value_utype,
  File "/usr/local/hadoop/cassandra211/bin/../pylib/cqlshlib/formatting.py", line 200
    if local.tm_isdst !=
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: in the if condition "if local.tm_isdst != " you are not comparing it any value. I have corrected it and took the code from previous cassandra version but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Naresh You're right, that line should be `if local.tm_isdst != 0`.  I have no idea how that was missed.  I'm sorry that this fix didn't work for you (even with the `!= 0:`).  I was able to get this to work on 2.1.8, but I see that it does not in 2.2.x.  My guess is that version must be farther along with some additional changes.  Let me see if I can make it work.

Comment: What is the JIRA bug Id and when it can be fixed (tentatively)?

Comment: hi, i´m using cassandra driver for node.js and it´s also `select`ing the timestamp column without an offset (it sets it to UTC). cqlsh is doing this too (`[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]`), I don't know how to `insert` the timestamp for it to be stored/queried/displayed correctly, please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

CQLSH default using UTC timezone so you need to check and  modify cassandra/conf/cqlshrc.sample file to update timezone as below.
;; Display timezone
;timezone = Etc/UTC

if not then you need to install 'pytz' python library

Hope this will work for you.